# Example of using save_pos subtype (luatex)

Tags: luatex, examples

Luatex manual mention  `save_pos` (page 136) a subtype of whatsit node, Is there anyone who can give us a simple example of its use with lualatex.

Comment: it's the node from \savepos, which is the same as pdftex \pdfsavepos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`save_pos` is the whatsit that is inserted by `\savepos` (the LuaTeX name for `\pdfsavepos`.) Using it directly would be quite rare because you would normally just use `\savepos` in TeX code or, if you want to access the position though Lua, you just use `pdf.getpos()` with `\latelua` directly.

But you could use it to implement you own version on `\pdfsavepos`:

```
% plain TeX, but you can also add `\documentclass` etc. to make it LaTeX...

% Don't do this in regular code, just use `\savepos`.
\def\pdfsavepos{\directlua{
  node.write(node.new("whatsit", "save_pos"))
}}
\pdfsavepos
% Write the coordinates of that point to the log file:
\write-1{The page starts at \the\lastxpos, \the\lastypos.}
\bye
```

The same example with `pdf.getpos()` and `\latelua`:

```
\latelua{
  texio.write_nl('log', ("The page starts at \csstring\%i, \csstring\%i."):format(pdf.getpos()))
}
\bye
```